# Why this function is not surjective?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$f: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ defined by

$f(x,y) = ( x+y , xy )$

MY claim:

By solving for (x,y)

Assume 
$f(x,y) = ( x+y , xy ) = (a,b).$

I get $x = a +\sqrt \frac{ a^2-4b}{4}$ and $ x = \frac{a}{2} +\sqrt \frac{ a^2-4b}{4}$

Comment: It was just a problem in a competitive exam problem

Comment: You say $y=x$, but then you also give different specification of $y$ and $x$ in terms of $a$ and $b$. Also, why do you have $\sqrt{a}^2$? Why not just $a$? And can you clarify what your claim is? Are you saying that you believe it is surjective, and that for arbitrary $a,b$ we can define $x,y$ in the way you suggest?

Comment: So what happens if $a^2 - 4b < 0$?

Comment: @RisingStar Your solutions are still wrong. But note that if $a^2<4b$ then there is no real solution, which answers your question.

Comment: $a^2 - 4b = (x-y)^2 \geq 0$. so i think discriminant is always positive

Comment: No, that's not how it works. You want to be able to 'make' *any* $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R^2}$ for the function to be surjective. You cannot make $(a,b)$'s where $a^2-4b < 0$, e.g. the point $(0,1)$ is not in the range of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

On solving $$x+y=a\ \ ;xy=b$$you get $$x={a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}\over 2}\ \ ;\ \ y={a-\sqrt{a^2-4b}\over 2}$$

Since $\forall \ a,b$ such that $a^2\lt 4b$ the image has no preimage($x,y$ are not defined), $\therefore$ The fuction is not surjective.

Comment: $a^2 - 4b = (x-y)^2 \geq 0$. so i think discriminant is always positive

Comment: @RisingStar You didn't get it. $x,y$ are to be found , they are not given. $a,b$ is given. Take for example $a=x+y=1,b=xy=2$. this is an image point. What is its preimage?

Comment: Thanks. Ya Got it. It was just a block.

Answer (score 2):

Try $(x+y, xy) = (0, 1)$.

Then $x+y=0$ implies $y = -x$.

So $xy = 1$ becomes $-x^2 = 1$ or $x^2 = -1$, which has no real solution.

In general,

$x+y = a$ implies y = a - x$.

So $xy = b$ becomes $x(a-x) = b$ or $x^2 -ax + b = 0$

You get $(x,y) \in \left\{
    \left(
        \dfrac{a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2},
        \dfrac{a - \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2}
    \right),
    \left(
        \dfrac{a - \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2},
        \dfrac{a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2}
    \right)
\right\}$

and there will be

- Two solutions when $a^2 - 4b > 0$.
- One solution when $a^2 - 4b = 0$.
- No solution when $a^2 - 4b < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

For example

$$f(x,y)=(1,2)\implies \begin{cases}x+y=1\implies y=1-x\\{}\\xy=2\end{cases}\implies$$

$$2=xy=x(1-x)\implies x^2-x+2=0$$

and this last quadratic has no real solutions as it s discriminant is negative.

Comment: but $a^2 \geq 4b$ happens always in the solution i have obtained. so by that case its surjective.

Comment: @RisingStar I really can't say what you did get as you didn't show your whole work, but isn't the above counterexample clear?

Comment: That's fine. I am convinced with your example.

Comment: @RisingStar Good. I wonder why you thought the discriminant of the corresponding quadratic is always positive or at least non-negative...

Comment: $a^2 - 4b = (x-y)^2 \geq 0$. so i think discriminant is always positive

Comment: Why do you think that's the discriminant??

Answer (score 0):

Try with $(a,b) = (2,3)$.
The system of equations $ x+y = 2 & xy = 3 $ can't be solved.

You make a mistake in your reasoning when you consider the square root without checking if the quantity under square root is non negative.